# Examples of a full Hilbert C(X)-bimodule E such that the crossed product $C(X) \rtimes_E \mathbb{Z}$ is simple?

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, hilbert-modules

Let $A = C(X)$ be a commutative $C^*$-algebra. An example of a full finitely generated Hilbert $A$-bimodule E such that the crossed product $C(X) \rtimes_E \mathbb{Z}$, as [defined by Abadie, Eilers and Exel](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1998-350-08/S0002-9947-98-02133-3/) is simple is given by $E =C(X)$ viewed as a bimodule over itself with mulitplication on the right induced by a minimal homeomorphism $\alpha$ of X. In that case, the crossed product is just the usual one, $C(X) \rtimes_\alpha \mathbb{Z}$.

Is there an example of a full Hilbert $A$-bimodule E such that the crossed product $C(X) \rtimes_E \mathbb{Z}$ is simple but $E$ does not come from a minimal homeomorphism?

Comment: I think you can get an example in which E is the (right) module of sections of a 1-dimensional bundle of Hilbert spaces over X, and the action on the left is twisted by a minimal homeomorphism of X.   I suspect this is as general an example as you can get.

Comment: Thanks, Ruy. So if I understand correctly, the case which yields the usual crossed product $C(X) \rtimes_{\alpha} \mathbb{Z}$ by a minimal homeomorphism $\alpha : X \to X$ corresponds to a trivial line bundle twisted by $\alpha$? So if $X$ has nontrivial line bundles, one can in principal obtain a $C^*$-algebra nonisomorphic to $C(X) \rtimes_{\alpha} \mathbb{Z}$? Will they be Morita equivalent?

Comment: Regarding your last question, the answer is no: the Morita class of the crossed product does depend on the line bundle.  A student of mine (http://ppgmtm.posgrad.ufsc.br/files/2017/09/Julio-Carceres.pdf) has recently computed the K-groups of the algebra arising from the Bott bundle over the two sphere (with trivial  $\alpha$), from where you may deduce that it is not Morita equivalent to the crossed product by the same automorphism and the trivial bundle.  It is true that the identity homeomorphism is not minimal, but I'd suspect one can get similar examples with a minimal homeomorphism.